Folland question #1.2.5
Here is the question I am starring at:
If $\mathcal{M}$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\epsilon,$ then $\mathcal{M}$ is the union of $\sigma$-algebras generated by $\mathcal{F}$ as $\mathcal{F}$ ranges over all countable subsets of $\epsilon.$(Hint: Show that the latter object is a $\sigma$-algebra.)
I do not understand what this question is teaching us, I do not understand its statement, could anyone explain it to me please?
I also do not understand why the hint will prove the required.Could anyone explain it to me please?

I think it would help to transform the statement into a less wordy expression.
To parse the exercise, first note that "If $\mathcal{M}$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\epsilon$" corresponds to the expression $\mathcal{M}=\sigma(\epsilon)$. The statement that "$\mathcal{M}$ is the union of $\sigma$-algebras generated by $\mathcal{F}$ as $\mathcal{F}$ ranges over countable subsets of $\epsilon$" can be written as $\mathcal{M}=\cup_{i\in \mathcal{I}}\sigma(\mathcal{F}_i)$, where $\mathcal{I}$ is some index set for ranging over the countable subsets of $\epsilon$.
The statement asks us to prove that $\sigma(\epsilon)=\cup_{i\in \mathcal{I}}\sigma(\mathcal{F}_i)$. One inclusion is straightforward.

 For any $i\in \mathcal{I}$, $\mathcal{F}_i\subset \epsilon$, so $\sigma(\mathcal{F}_i)\subset \sigma(\epsilon)$. Hence, $\sigma(\epsilon)\supset\cup_{i\in \mathcal{I}}\sigma(\mathcal{F}_i)$.

The other inclusion is where the hint is used. Specifically, it tells us that $\sigma(\cup_{i\in \mathcal{I}}\sigma(\mathcal{F}_i))=\cup_{i\in\mathcal{I}} \sigma(\mathcal{F}_i)$ which is useful because...

 Any set $\mathcal{F}_i=\{a_i\}$ for some set $a_i\in \epsilon$ is countable and $\sigma(\mathcal{F}_i)\supset \{a_i\}$. Therefore, $\epsilon=\cup_i \{a_i\}\subset \cup_{i\in \mathcal{I}}\sigma(\mathcal{F}_i)$. And so, with the result of the hint, we obtain $\sigma(\epsilon)\subset \sigma(\cup_{i\in \mathcal{I}}\sigma(\mathcal{F}_i))=\cup_{i\in\mathcal{I}} \sigma( \mathcal{F}_i)$.

